How much do sub-surf impact real-time rendering or is there alternative solutions?
This is a Blender newbie speaking.
I wanted to make a game about growing flowers. My plan is to make the animation in Blender and import the animated mesh into unity.
I do have made a looking good base mesh for a section of stem + leaf. Though, the shading on some part of the mesh do not look satisfying enough, as the sharp geometric contour is still noticeable. I wanted to avoid this because a large part of the game is about looking at the flower growing from seeds.

I do tried to add a sub-surf modifier and the shading were great! Only that I noticed the vertices count ramped up by more than ten-fold (1131 -> 18009). How much will this impact the run-time rendering? If I wanted to avoid this, what potentially could I do?
Thank you all in advance for any of your comments.
Sincerely,
Anyu

You can render a test scene one time without a subdivision surface modifier and a second time with the modifier. There you have your difference. Of course it has an influence, but it's hard to give a general answer, it depends on your mesh, the levels of subdivision, the rest of the scene... and in Blender you can set different subdivision levels for viewport and render. And you can render with the modifier on the object. For Unity you have to apply the modifier so it becomes a real mesh. How much this effects the Unity performance, I have no idea. But this site is about Blender, not Unity.

Okay, thank you!

To be honest I think you are asking yourself the wrong question here. Instead of wondering the performance cost, you should wonder how to get the best looking result without having to waste performances on more subdivision. If you are interested in that, I invite you to [edit] your question to orient it to that purpose, and include closer screenshots in edit mode of your mesh, why not even share your file.
